# No power to furnace

Tags: hvac

My furnace wouldn't come on after changing the transformer.  I have power to the transformer & motherboard, I checked with a power meter.  I noticed the limit reset switch is unassembled.  My cousin a HVAC person bypassed it but I don't know how to restore power.

Comment: "Unassembled"? Do you mean tripped?

Comment: Which transformer? What make/model? Where are you located?

Comment: What is the make and model of the furnace?  Does the furnace control board have a fuse on it?  If so, check to make sure it's not blown.  Also, you should not be running the furnace with a bypassed high limit. This can result in damage to the unit, and/or a fire.